# How to access JSON fields using variables

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to access the data in a JSON file by defining a list of query strings so that I can loop through them and dynamically extract the data.

In the example below, I trying to extract the "[1]['name']" and pass it as a variable.

```
   data_set = {1: [1, {'name':'bob'}, 3], 2: [1, {'name':'bill'}, 3],3: [1, {'name':'fred'}, 3]}

   for d in data_set:
       print(data_set[d][1]['name'])
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
    query_list = r'[1][''name'']'
    print(data_set[d][1]['name'])
```

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you have a string like `"[1]['name']"` which you want to use to traverse the dictionary / list in depth? Where is this string coming from?

Comment: I want to define the string. Actually it will be a list of strings and the actual JSON will be much complex.  I want to be able to easily define the variables that I want to extract from it.

Comment: If it's you who defines the string, I'd rather use lists, like `[1, 'name']` and then iterate over it.

Comment: Yes, a list like that could work as long as the depth is know.  In some instances two levels but then in others 3 or 4 levels into the JSON are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in control of the strings, I'd rather use lists to represent paths, such as `[1, 1, 'name']`:

```
def get_nested(value, path):
    for p in path:
        value = value[p]
    return value
```

Then:

```
>>> data_set = {1: [1, {'name': 'bob'}, 3]}
>>> get_nested(data_set, [1, 1, 'name'])
>>> 'bob'
```

If you're more into functional style, you can also define `get_nested()` as:

```
import functools, operator
def get_nested(value, path):
    return functools.reduce(operator.getitem, path, value)
```

If you don't know the keys of `data_set` in advance, you can iterate over its values and pass them to `get_nested()`:

```
for val in data_set.values():
    for query in queries:
        print(get_nested(val, query))
```

Comment: Very close.   Then I can loop through the following calling get_nested.
queries = [[1, 1, 'name'],[1, 1, 'name'],[1, 3, 'city']]

However, the first variable will "d" will be iterated over.  Would you recommend me to send it to "get_nested" as a parameter or append it to the variable from queries before sending it?

Comment: @Justin if you don't know `d`s in advance, I'd just iterate over the original dict and pass the values to `get_nested()` as the first argument. I'll update the example.

Comment: Updating the first element of the list as I iterated over it worked well.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, the property names (in this case `1`, `2`, `3`) should be enclosed in double quotes such as `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"`within your JSON data. Then use `json.loads` function along with a cursor containing an `if` condition to extract the desired value such as

```
import json
data_set = '{"1": [1, {"name":"bob"}, 3], "2": [1, {"name":"bill"}, 3],"3": [1, {"name":"fred"}, 3]}'

loaded_json = json.loads(data_set)
for i in loaded_json:
    if int(i) == 1:
        print( loaded_json[i] )
```

Agreed. Expanding on your code I am added an extra element to the JSON.  I wanted to put the [1]['name'] and [3]['city'] into a string list so that I can loop through the list extracting data.  The JSON will be much more complex and I will be extracting a large set of variables.

```
    data_set = '{"1": [1, {"name":"bob"}, 3,{"city":"London"}], "2": [1, {"name":"bill"}, 3,{"city":"Madrid"}],"3": [1, {"name":"fred"}, 3,{"city":"Portland"}]}'

    loaded_json = json.loads(data_set)
    for i in loaded_json:
          print(loaded_json[i][1]['name'])
          print(loaded_json[i][3]['city'])
```